# What are the benefits of using JSON1 in SQLite?

Tags: json, sqlite

I am looking into the various features of Sqlite.  I have come across the JSON1 extension and I am wondering when is it a good idea to embed a json string in a database field?  Does it slow down queries?  What are the best practices of embedding json in a database field?  Specifically when used with the Sqlite extension JSON1.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a text type, it just has a convenient api that allows you treat that text as JSON.

> The json1 extension is a loadable extension that implements **fifteen application-defined SQL functions** and **two table-valued functions** that are useful for managing JSON content stored in an SQLite database. Twelve of the fourteen SQL functions are scalar functions.

From [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)